# How to add a output result with 4 decimals?

Tags: javascript, html

HTML

```
<div class="item main">
    <h1>Second Heading</h1>
<p>This is my second paragraph<br>
<input type="text" id="input">
  <button id="kg">Convert to Kg</button><br><br>
  <button id="pound">Convert to Pound</button>
  <input type="text" id="output">

    </div>
```

Javascript

```
  let kgbtn = document.getElementById('kg');
  let poundbtn = document.getElementById('pound');

 /*This is my converter from KG to Pound*/

 kgbtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
 let input = document.getElementById('input').value;
 document.getElementById('output').value = input / 2.205 + "kg";                    
 })

/*This is my converter from Pound to KG*/
poundbtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
let input = document.getElementById('input').value;
document.getElementById('output').value = input * 2.205 + "Pound";
})
```

Can anyone please help me out with adding four decimals? I'm quite new to this javascript and would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `toFixed()` method

```js
const num = 12345678;

const res = num.toFixed(4);

console.log(res);
// expected output = 1234,5678
```

```js
function financial(x) {
  return Number.parseFloat(x).toFixed(2);
}

console.log(financial(123.456));
// expected output: "123.46"

console.log(financial(0.004));
// expected output: "0.00"

console.log(financial('1.23e+5'));
// expected output: "123000.00"
```

Here are examples similar to  what you want

[`Number.prototype.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method.

```js
const num = 123.456789;
console.log(num.toFixed(4));
```